# Huge Webforms Project To MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I know this is a ridiculous pie-in-the-sky request, but I have a project I started a long time ago in WebForms that has grown into a relatively large and stable business that I would like to convert to MVC. However, for the past year I have been working for a company that uses MVC exclusively and I really like the flexibility a lot more. As you might guess, I want to change my current project over to MVC, but I'm starting to think that I'm stuck with WebForms, that is, unless anyone has any suggestions on how to do it.

I was thinking of maybe just starting a new project and manually converting the functionality, but that could take AGES and could possibly introduce new bugs, although only on the page functionality code (OO code is broken out). Bad idea?

I know "if it ain't broke don't fix it", but I'm a developer, so if it ain't broke, I'm not trying hard enough :)

For those trying to close the question because it is unclear what I'm asking, **how do you convert a large Webforms project to MVC?** Or, I guess, what is the best way, or are there tools, etc.

PS: Budget isn't an issue because this is a personal dev project.

Comment: Any closers/downvoters care to comment on what's wrong/unclear with this question?

Comment: You should try narrowing your question down.  Considering we don't know anything about your project its going to be impossible to answer the best way to convert it.  Its like asking how you could convert my standard car to a race car?  Who knows? What are the tires, brakes, suspension, body, engine, frame, axel, ... the rest of the components... like?

Comment: @jfar ok that's fair i suppose. however, i was just asking for general advice, not a step by step manual on how to do it.

Comment: yeah, so back to my example.  "you make a car a racecar by upgrading its component one piece at a time".  Is that going to be helpful? ---- Asking for conversion tools would be fine or asking for a specific piece of your project that looks hard to convert would be ok.  Your current question is just way to broad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert website from webforms to asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790679/convert-website-from-webforms-to-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

Webforms applications can be run inside of MVC, so it does allow you some leeway to move to MVC at your own pace.

I developed a dashboard app for our company in Webforms.  As it started getting bigger and bigger than I originally planned I decided to move to MVC to better handle the scaling out.  I followed the instructions [here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc) in order to convert my project to MVC and still allow webforms pages to show.

It worked well, but it wasn't perfect though.  My webform's GUI (Webform controls) were messed up slightly (collapsible panels not collapsing properly, modals wouldn't hide, etc..).  None of this affected the overall functionality of the site, but it did look bad.  I did end up just spending the next 3 days moving over most of my webform pages to MVC so I didn't have the graphical issues.

Another thing to be aware of is that while MVC and Webforms can share master pages, you can't put webform controls in the master pages.  If this is required (like it was for me due to putting the script manager and some other things in the master page) you have to chain the master pages together to keep them in sync.  So MVC pages use the MVC.Master, while webform pages use my Webforms.Master (which has all the webform controls required), and the Webforms.Master actually uses MVC.Master as **its** master page.  So far this has worked out well.

In regards to the conversion of the actual webform pages to MVC, that was easy for me only because I have my business layer finely separated out anyways.  All I had to do was rewrite (and restructure!) the GUI to work with the business layers.  If your business layer is inside your webform code-behind sections, this will be a greater.

I think I got a bad case of editing and stream of consciousness, so I hope this makes sense or helps.  I am glad I converted to MVC, although my app still has some webforms aspects working happily in it.  In Most cases, doing a gradual conversion will work, but it really depends on how modular your app is.

Comment: paragraph 2 doesn't make sense, webforms wouldn't be responsible for UI bugs, its all in the html/css

Comment: No problem.  I think I forgot that you do need to plan out the GUI conversion.  The way that the GUI works in webforms will probably be different than in MVC, and if you try to make the MVC work exactly the same the whole web request workflow will be different.  Just get an understanding before starting the GUI rewrite on how things need to work under MVC.

Comment: @jfar: The GUI bugs were all in Webform controls.  I don't know what exactly caused them, but the html and CSS were exactly the same before and after my conversion.  They were bugs in the way the controls themselves were functioning, not in the display of them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to move it all in one mega step, it won't work.

> I know "if it ain't broke don't fix it", but I'm a developer, so if it ain't broke, I'm not trying hard enough :)

I'll say it again: if it ain't broke don't fix it. Seriously, don't go all around moving code you are not even working on. That's usually unfeasible.

Only move pieces you are working on and only others closely related to those. If there are no bugs (right ...) then pick requested features, moving code you need to modify for the feature anyway.

Over time, you'll be able to take biggest steps, just because you'll have many more pieces in place and also more experience with it.